# Making stored function based confirmation / callback system work with multiple processes in django + nginx

Tags: django, nginx, process, callback, asynccallback

Our callback system worked such that during a request where you needed more user input you would run the following:

```
def view(req):
    # do checks, maybe get a variable.
    bar = req.bar()
    def doit():
       foo = req.user
       do_the_things(foo, bar)
    req.confirm(doit, "Are you sure you want to do it")
```

From this, the server would store the function object in a dictionary, with a UID as a key that would be send to the client, where a confirmation dialog would be shown. When OK is pressed another request is sent to another view which looks up the stored function object and runs it.

This works in a single process deployment. However with nginx, if there's a process pool greater than 1, a different process gets the confirmation request, and thus doesn't have the stored function, and can no run.

We've looked into ways to force nginx to use a certain process for certain requests, but haven't found a solution.

We've also looked into multiprocessing libraries and celery, however there doesn't seem to be a way to send a predefined function into another process.

Can anyone suggest a method that will allow us to store a function to run later when the request for continuing might come from a separate process?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what the function will do? Why do you need to define it inline for example?

Comment: There are many instances of this, it's a callback API.  used for example when deleting rows. First request says what rows to delete, then the confirmation request doesn't define the rows again, it just has a callback ID. Defined in line so you can use data from the original request.

Comment: Basically user clicks button which sends a request to the server, server responds that it wants user confirmation, and closes that connection by sending a confirmation message and a ID for that callback. saves the inline function, and if another request comes in to the x_callback url it looks up the ID given in the  new request and runs the function, and returns the output.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a good reason to use a callback defined as an inline function here.

The web is a stateless environment. You can never be certain of getting the same server process two requests in a row, and your code should never be written to store data in memory.

Instead you need to put data into a data store of some kind. In this case, the [session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/sessions/) is the ideal place; you can store the IDs there, then redirect the user to a view that pops that key from the session and runs the process on the relevant IDs. Again, no need for an inline function at all.